# How to generate the AWS root account ARN in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

**The situation**

I am generating a KMS Key in CloudFormation. According to the [KMS policy documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html), it is crucial to create a policy where the `Principal` is the account itself, in order for IAM policies to be able to grant access to the key.

**The question**

How can I create the ARN for the account root in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 10):

For those who use YAML for their CloudFormation templates:

```
!Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root
```

Answer (score 5):

**The answer**

```
{  
   "Fn::Join":[  
      ":",
      [  
         "arn:aws:iam:",
         {  
            "Ref":"AWS::AccountId"
         },
         "root"
      ]
   ]
}
```

**Why does this work?**

First, let's examine the line, `"Ref":"AWS::AccountId"`. This is a [pseudo parameter reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html), which is a fancy way of saying that it is a parameter that comes out of the box with CloudFormation. There are many such parameters. This one happens to give us the account ID, which is crucial for constructing the ARN.

Now, the rest is just the creation of an ARN using this account ID. `Fn::Join` is simply [a CloudFormation built-in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html) that allows concatenation of strings. This is crucial when combining references with string constants (or other references) as we are doing here.

The result is something like...

```
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root
```

Comment: You can find the `AccountId` here https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/security_credentials (you must be signed in)

Comment: This does not consider the variations for different region types, like `arn:aws-cn:iam`, `arn:aws-iso:iam`, and `arn:aws-iso-b:iam`.