# Why does this AWS CloudFormation script throw "Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals" error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms

I am trying to:

1. Create a CMK
2. Create a new bucket that requires/enforces use of that
   CMK

Code is from [here](https://blog.flowlab.no/aws-cloudformation-snippets-db8c36cf5483)

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Example template with Customer Master Key and S3 bucket

Resources:
Bucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
    BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
        - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
            KMSMasterKeyID: !Sub "arn:aws:kms:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${CMKAlias}"
            SSEAlgorithm: "aws:kms"

CMKAlias:
    Type: "AWS::KMS::Alias"
    Properties:
    AliasName: "alias/test/cmk"
    TargetKeyId: !Ref CMK

CMK:
    Type: "AWS::KMS::Key"
    Properties:
    Description: "My CMK"
    Enabled: True
    EnableKeyRotation: true
    KeyPolicy:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
        - Sid: "Allow root IAM"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
            AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/root"
            Action:
            - "kms:*"
            Resource: "*"

Outputs:
CMKId:
    Value: !Ref CMK
CMKArn:
    Value: !GetAtt CMK.Arn
CMKAliasArn:
    Value: !Sub "arn:aws:kms:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${CMKAlias}"
Bucket:
    Value: !Ref Bucket
```

The errors are:

```
The following resource(s) failed to create: [CMK]. . Rollback requested by user.

Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals. 
(Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400;
Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocumentException;
Request ID: zzzzzz-zzzzz-zzzzz)
```

I believe the issue is with this line:

```
AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/root"
```

I see from [intrinsic-function-reference-sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) that !Sub is a function to replace values, and I see from [pseudo-parameter-reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html) that ${AWS::AccountId} is a valid pseudo parameter, so I do not understand why that line is failing.

I see from [how-to-generate-the-aws-root-account-arn-in-cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671361/how-to-generate-the-aws-root-account-arn-in-cloudformation) that this is considered a valid way in YAML:

```
!Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:root
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indents are not correct.

Try it as the following:

```
KeyPolicy:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Sid: "Allow root IAM"
        Effect: "Allow"
        Principal:
        AWS: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/root"
        Action:
          - "kms:*"
        Resource: "*"
```

Comment: The same applies to the block starting with `- ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:`